# Updating gmail draft message with gmail-api

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am trying to update a draft message in a script editor (script.google.com) which is attached to a google spreadsheet.

```
function updatetest(){
var base64UpdatedEmail = 
Base64.encode('From:me@gmail.com\nTo:another@notemail.com\nSubject:Hello 
again.....\n\nGoodbye again'); 
var request =  Gmail.Users.Drafts.update({
// also tried here-'userId': 'me',
'id': '1560722027154054758',
'message': {'raw': base64UpdatedEmail}
,'send': false

},'me');

Logger.log(request);

}
```

This produces the following error:
Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-5 only (line 32, file "Code")

However if I run this in my browser it works:

```
function updatedraft(){
      var base64UpdatedEmail = Base64.encode('From:me@gmail.com\nTo:another@notemail.com\nSubject:Hello 
again.....\n\nGoodbye again');

      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.update({
        'userId': 'me',
        'id': '1560722027154054758',
        'message': {
            'raw': base64UpdatedEmail
        }    
        ,'send': false
      });
      request.execute(function(response) {
          console.log('response='+JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        })
  }
```

(in both examples above I have changed the actual To and from email addresses)

For reference I am using:https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update
however the javascript browser example there does not work and has to be simplified as in my browser example above.

I really need to get this working in script editor and have tried dozens of argument permutations which all produce the same error, any ideas?